# Why this form sends two identical messages on submit?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This form is quite simple

```
<form action="/write.php?action=letter" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1">
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I submit it this way

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.name("body"));
el.sendKeys("Hello");
el.submit();
```

But the user recieves two identical messages.
Why this form sends two identical messages on submit?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That code you showed looks harmless enough. But there could be any kind of weirdness going on in the code you **don't** show us (such as JavaScript in the HTML, surrounding code in the webdriver) ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer it's almoust all the content of the form. This form opens in a mini window by this link `<a href="javascript:OpenMiniWin('write.php?userId=1', 500, 600,'Wrire a letter');">write</a>`

Comment: So MRE? Yes or no? What's the minimum ammount of code you can provide that reproduces this issue?